# Rails - Insert on a has_many through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I have two classes, users and opportunities, that utilize a join table with a has_many :through relationship to allow a user to enrol in one to multiple opportunities (and allow one opportunity to have many users enrol).

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :opportunity_enrolments, :class_name => 'OpportunityEnrolment', foreign_key: "user_id"
  has_many :opportunities, through: :opportunity_enrolments, foreign_key: "opportunity_id"
  has_secure_password
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
class Opportunity < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :opportunity_enrolments, :class_name => 'OpportunityEnrolment'
  has_many :users, through: :opportunity_enrolments
end
class OpportunityEnrolment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :opportunity
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Users will only enrol in an opportunity when both the user and the opportunity exist. So the enrol functionality will take place outside the creation of user and opportunity, those happen separately and work fine. I thought that I could use the OpportunityEnrolment.create method when viewing an Opportunity to add a new row to the opportunity_enrolments table with the below form and controller.

**opportunity/show.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: OpportunityEnrolment.create, local: true) do |form| %>
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @opportunity.voppname %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Shortdescr:</strong>
  <%= @opportunity.shortdescr %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**opportunity_enrolments_controller.rb**

```
def create      
   @opportunity_enrolment = OpportunityEnrolment.new(user_id: current_user.id, opportunity_id: @opportunity.id)

  error checking and .save...
end
```

However, the @opportunity.id in my form is not being passed to the OpportunityEnrolment.create method, so I'm getting an "Undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass" error upon submission. I've tried it a different way, with a hidden field in the form (understand its not secure) and the object is still not passed through, but I get past the Undefined method error.

How can I pass the object information (Opportunity) to another class (OpportunityEnrolments) so I can add a row to the opportunity_enrolments table?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be done using a nested route instead of passing the opportunity
id in the form.

```
# config/routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # create the route: GET /opportunities/:id
  # helper: opportunity_path(opportunity || opportunity_id)
  # handled by: OpportunitiesController#show
  resources :opportunities, only: :show do

    # create the route: POST /opportunities/:opportunity_id/opportunity_enrolments
    # helper: opportunity_opportunity_enrolments_path(opportunity || opportunity_id)
    # handled by: OpportunityEnrolmentsController#create
    resources :opportunity_enrolments, only: :create
  end

end
```

```
# app/controllers/opportunity_enrolments_controller.rb
class OpportunityEnrolmentsController < ApplicationController
  # opportunity should be set for every nested action, create in this scenario
  before_action :set_opportunity, only: :create

  def create
    # initialize a new opportunity enrolment with opportunity id set to
    # the id of the current opportunity
    @opportunity_enrolment = @opportunity.opportunity_enrolments.build
    # set the user id equal to the current user
    @opportunity_enrolment.user = current_user

    # assign the passed attributes by the form and try to save the record
    # if your form doesn't contain any attributes, call #save instead
    if @opportunity_enrolment.update(opportunity_enrolment_params)
      redirect_to @opportunity
    else
      # display errors using @opportunity_enrolment.errors in the form, see note
      render 'opportunities/show' 
    end
  end

  private

  def opportunity_enrolment_params
    # if you only need to set the attributes opportunity_id and user_id
    # you can leave this call out and call #save instead of #update
    # ...
  end

  def set_opportunity
    # params[:opportunity_id] is retrieved from the current path, it is not
    # a query or request body param
    @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
  end
end
```

```
<% # app/views/opportunities/show.html.erb %>

<% # If rendered from opportunity show: opportunity enrolment is not set thus a new     %>
<% # opportunity enrolment will be initialized. If rendered from the opportunity        %>
<% # enrolment create action: opportunity enrolment will already be present with errors %>
<% # set, no new opportunity will be initialized.                                       %>
<% @opportunity_enrolment ||= @opportunity.opportunity_enrolments.build %>

<% # Passing an array containing an opportunity and an opportunity enrolment will build  %>
<% # the path in 3 steps. 1) Is opportunity a new record? Use /opportunities, if not use %>
<% # /opportunities/:id. 2) Is opportunity enrolment a new record? Use                   %>
<% # /opportunity_enrolments, if not use /opportunity_enrolments/:id. 3) Is the last     %>
<% # element in the array a new record? Use POST, if not use PUT.                        %>
<% # Combining the above together you get the path:                                      %>
<% # POST /opportunities/:opportunity_id/opportunity_enrolments                          %>
<% # Handled by OpportunityEnrolmentsController#create (see routes).                     %>
<%= form_with model: [@opportunity, @opportunity_enrolment], local: true do |form| %>
  <p><strong>Name:</strong><%= @opportunity.voppname %></p>
  <p><strong>Shortdescr:</strong><%= @opportunity.shortdescr %></p>
  <p><%= form.submit %></p>
<% end %>
```

**Note**: If you are going to read up on [nested resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources) don't skip
the part about shallow nesting. It keeps your routes and application cleaner.
The page for error access can be found [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validations-overview-errors).

Comment: Awesome, I'll try this out!

Comment: I'm close to getting it to work, but getting an error in the opportunity_enrolment_params private method (param is missing or the value is empty: opportunity_enrolment). The code I have in the private method is params.require(:opportunity_enrolment).permit(:user_id, :opportunity_id). Currently debugging but I'm guessing that maybe the user_id parameter is null, so that is why I'm getting the error?

Comment: Changed the params.require to a params.permit, which seems to have gotten around the issue. I'm getting a RecordNotUnique error now that I'm trying to work through, but from the parameters spit out in the error, looks like everything is getting passed through correctly.

Comment: Unique error was my own fault, added values to the database via the command line that rails wasn't aware of. Had to delete all my table date and everything worked perfectly, thanks for the help! Now to figure out HOW it worked ;)

Comment: I'll add in some explaining comments.

Comment: @NathanM If you only need to set the *opportunity_id* and *user_id* attributes you can leave out `@opportunity_enrolment.update(opportunity_enrolment_params)` and instead just call `@opportunity_enrolment.save`.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the comments! Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a hidden field, you will need to instantiate the opportunity in the create action in the opportunity_enrolments_controller.

```
def create
  @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
  @opportunity_enrolment = OpportunityEnrolment.new(user_id: current_user.id, opportunity_id: @opportunity.id)
end
```

In the form:

```
<%= form_with(model: OpportunityEnrolment.create, local: true) do |form| %>
<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @opportunity.voppname %>
</p>
<p>
  <strong>Shortdescr:</strong>
  <%= @opportunity.shortdescr %>
  <%= form.hidden_field :opportunity_id, value: @opportunity.id %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= form.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Close to a solution. Rails does not like @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id]). Getting a "Cannot find opportunity without an ID" even though the parameters appear to be passing through -           
Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"8QB1soyRpqGPeoy98vjRXcVNtFaJRjnZT7oNSmHnPd2TJxAWS9hT6PYqYuEAHToDDiAtH1cE6sSGbLVNyJteVg==", "opportunity_enrolment"=>{"opportunity_id"=>"2"}, "commit"=>"Enrol"}

Comment: @NathanM, you would need to do params[:opportunity_enrolment][:opportunity_id]

Comment: Thanks for the comments, went with the nested resource instead.